# Looking for a sci-fi detective novel

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a sci-fi detective novel. I think the cover had some sort of hindu gods on it, maybe Ganesh. The name played along the lines of Karma Detective, or Karma Drugs, or something like that. I remember that the detective used "karma" or something similar, to solve crimes... maybe. I also remember that airships were involved, as well as drug usage.

Comment: Too far off to be the answer (I suspect), but [Ian McDonald's *River of Gods*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_of_Gods) has some similar stuff going on.

Answer (score 2):

There's no connection to the Hindu gods or airships, but Jonathan Lethem's "Gun With Occasional Music" is a sci-fi noir in a future world where karma is tracked via credit card, and drug use is rampant.  (I'm actually reading it now, and discovered it via [this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48022/what-poetic-old-detective-noir-book-has-mutants-smuggled-out-of-a-ghetto-being-b))  The cover has no elephant, but it does have a kangaroo in a fedora.